# How to share memory (of SDRAM) between HPS and FPGA in Cyclone-V?

Tags: c, ram, intel-fpga, soc

I want to share memory between HPS and FPGA in Cyclone-V. I instantiated "sdram_slave" interface in Qsys(Platform Designer) with avalon master and everything.I want to send the base_address of memory in SDRAM from HPS to FPGA, so that FPGA can read the same data. The problem I am facing is, HPS has 1GB SDRAM(i.e, 2^30 - 1073741824  address locations), but I got address of my memory far greater than that(something like -3196356160-2^32). How is it Possible? How can I send the correct base_address of the memory I want to share with FPGA which is in the range of 0 to 2^30?

Here is my code,

```
#define soc_cv_av

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/mman.h> 
#include "hwlib.h" 
#include "socal/socal.h"
#include "socal/hps.h" 
#include "socal/alt_gpio.h"
#include "hps_0.h"

#define HW_REGS_BASE 0xFF200000
#define HW_REGS_SPAN 0x00200000
int fd;

void* axi_lw_virtual_base;

int main (){

    if( (fd=open("/dev/mem",(O_RDWR|O_SYNC)) ) == -1 ){
        printf("Error Could not open file /dev/mem\n");
        return 1;
    }

    axi_lw_virtual_base=mmap(NULL,HW_REGS_SPAN,(PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE),MAP_SHARED,fd,HW_REGS_BASE);
    if(axi_lw_virtual_base == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("AXI_LW Error Memory-Mapping Failed\n");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------
    volatile char arr[8192];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<8192; i++){
        arr[i] = (char)(65+i%25);
    }

    void *arr_base = &arr;
    printf("%u\n", arr_base); // outputs something in range of 3196356160 <--

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set bit 4 in L3 configuration register at 0xFF800000.

This bit enables the Lightweight HPS to FPGA AXI bridge in the main user space. 
Once this bit is set you can access the FPGA memory space through the bus.

Notice that the Lightweight bus is mapped at 0xFF200000 in the HPS memory space.
This means your FPGA addresses shall be remapped on top of this address when accessed from the HPS.

See the Cyclone V HPS address space information in the [Cyclone V Hard Processor System Technical Reference Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/cyclone-v/cv_54001.pdf), chapter "HPS Address Spaces".